# Android Data Binding + Mediator Live Data - Handling Lifecycle Events

Tags: android-fragments, mvvm, android-lifecycle, android-databinding, android-livedata

In my Android app I have a fragment where the user can simultaneously view and edit some object's attributes.

I'm using an MVVM architecture with data binding and a mediator live data that holds the Relation object being edited. Here's how it works:

1. Fragment inflates and binds the view (the layout xml).
2. During this process the Fragment has a ViewModel made.
3. The ViewModel will fetch the Relation object (and its attributes) from the database, and put it in a MediatorLiveData.
4. Thanks to data binding and binding adapters, the editText fields get set to the object's attributes automatically.
5. The user can then edit these editText fields and save.
6. Upon saving, the ViewModel will get the texts from the editTexts and use them to update the Relation object in the local database

Here's the problem: upon rotating the screen, the fragment gets destroyed and recreated. But I have no way to restore the editText contents. The binding will just reset the editText contents (because we didn't actually update the Relation object attributes yet, we only do that when the user presses 'save').

I can't use a Bundle / savedInstanceState because the binding will just overwrite that. Using a MediatorLiveData to hold the edited contents won't work either because the ViewModel gets destroyed upon rotation, so we lose that data.

Portion of the fragment layout. Note the data variable (viewmodel) and the data binding in the relationNameEditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".presentation.relationdetail.RelationDetailFragment">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="relationDetailViewModel"
            type="be.pjvandamme.farfiled.presentation.relationdetail.RelationDetailViewModel" />
    </data>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/relationDetailLayoutMargin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameLabelTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/nameLabel"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relationNameEditText"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/relationNameEditText"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/relationNameEditWidth"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextChips"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameLabelTextView"
                    app:relationName="@{relationDetailViewModel.relation}" />
```

The Fragment itself:

```
class RelationDetailFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: FragmentRelationDetailBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_relation_detail,
            container,
            false
        )

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

        val arguments = RelationDetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!)

        val relationDataSource = FarFiledDatabase.getInstance(application).relationDao

        val relationLifeAreaDataSource = FarFiledDatabase.getInstance(application).relationLifeAreaDao

        val viewModelFactory =
            RelationDetailViewModelFactory(
                arguments.relationId,
                relationDataSource,
                relationLifeAreaDataSource,
                application
            )

        val relationDetailViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(
                this, viewModelFactory).get(RelationDetailViewModel::class.java)

        binding.relationDetailViewModel = relationDetailViewModel

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        // stuff about chips

        val textWatcher = object: TextWatcher{ /* */ }

        binding.saveButton.isEnabled = false

        binding.relationNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        binding.relationSynopsisEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        binding.lifeAreaNowEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        // etc.

        relationDetailViewModel.enableSaveButton.observe(this, Observer{ /* */})

        relationDetailViewModel.showNameEmptySnackbar.observe(this, Observer{ /* */})

        relationDetailViewModel.navigateToRelationsList.observe(this, Observer{ /* */})

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

The viewmodel:

```
class RelationDetailViewModel (
    private val relationKey: Long?,
    val relationDatabase: RelationDao,
    val relationLifeAreaDatabase: RelationLifeAreaDao,
    application: Application
): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var viewModelJob = Job()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    private val relation = MediatorLiveData<Relation?>()
    fun getRelation() = relation

    private val relationLifeAreas = MediatorLiveData<List<RelationLifeArea?>>()
    fun getRelationLifeAreas() = relationLifeAreas

    // other LiveData's with backing properties, to trigger UI events

    init {
        initializeRelation()
    }

    private fun initializeRelation(){
        if(relationKey == null || relationKey == -1L) {
            initializeNewRelation()
            getAdorableAvatarFacialFeatures()
        }
        else {
            retrieveAvatarUrl()
            relation.addSource(
                relationDatabase.getRelationWithId(relationKey),
                relation::setValue)
            relationLifeAreas.addSource(
                relationLifeAreaDatabase.getAllRelationLifeAreasForRelation(relationKey),
                relationLifeAreas::setValue)
        }
    }

    private fun initializeNewRelation(){
        uiScope.launch{
            var relationId = insert(Relation(0L,"","",null,false))
            initializeLifeAreasForRelation(relationId)
            relation.addSource(
                relationDatabase.getRelationWithId(
                        relationId!!),
                relation::setValue)
            relationLifeAreas.addSource(
                relationLifeAreaDatabase.getAllRelationLifeAreasForRelation(
                    relationId!!),
                relationLifeAreas::setValue)
        }
    }

    private fun initializeLifeAreasForRelation(relationId: Long?){
        if(relationId != null){
            enumValues<LifeArea>().forEach {
                uiScope.launch{
                    var relationLifeArea = RelationLifeArea(0L,relationId,it,"")
                    insert(relationLifeArea)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun retrieveAvatarUrl(){
        uiScope.launch{
            var rel = get(relationKey!!)
            var avatarUrl = rel?.avatarUrl
            if (avatarUrl.isNullOrEmpty()){
                getAdorableAvatarFacialFeatures()
                _enableSaveButton.value = true
            }
            else
                _adorableAvatarString.value = rel?.avatarUrl
        }
    }

    private fun getAdorableAvatarFacialFeatures(){
        uiScope.launch{
            var getFeaturesDeferred = AdorableAvatarApi.retrofitService.getFacialFeatures()
            try{
                var result = getFeaturesDeferred.await()
                _adorableAvatarString.value = "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/face/" +
                        result.features.eyes.shuffled().take(1)[0] + "/" +
                        result.features.nose.shuffled().take(1)[0] + "/" +
                        result.features.mouth.shuffled().take(1)[0] + "/" +
                        result.features.COLOR_PALETTE.shuffled().take(1)[0]
                relation.value?.avatarUrl = _adorableAvatarString.value
            } catch(t:Throwable){
                // ToDo: what if this fails?? -> Try again later!!
                _adorableAvatarString.value = "Failure: " + t.message
            }
        }
    }

    fun onEditRelation(
        relationNameText: String,
        relationSynopsisText: String,
        lifeAreaNowText: String,
        // etc.
    ){
        _enableSaveButton.value = !compareRelationAttributes(
            relationNameText,
            relationSynopsisText,
            lifeAreaNow.Text,
            // etc
        )
    }

    private fun compareRelationAttributes(
        relationNameText: String,
        relationSynopsisText: String,
        lifeAreaNowText: String,
        // etc.
    ): Boolean {
        // checks if any of the attributes of the Relation object were changed
        // i.e. at least 1 of the editText fields has a text content that does
        // does not equal the corresponding attribute of the Relation object
    }

    fun onSave(
        name: String,
        synopsis: String,
        nowLA: String,
        // etc.
    ){
        if(!name.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            uiScope.launch {
                // update the DB
            }
            // TODO: this one should go away, need some sort of up button instead
            _navigateToRelationsList.value = true
        }
        else
            _showNameEmptySnackbar.value = true
    }

    // database suspend funs omitted

    // ui event handling functions

    override fun onCleared(){ /* cancel the viewModelJob */ }

}
```

The binding adapters:

```
@BindingAdapter("relationName")
fun TextView.setRelationName(item: Relation?){
    item?.let{
        text = item.name
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("relationSynopsis")
fun TextView.setRelationSynopsis(item: Relation?){
    item?.let{
        text = item.synopsis
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("relationLifeAreaNow")
fun TextView.setLifeAreaNowText(item: List<RelationLifeArea?>?){
    item?.let{
        item.forEach{
            if(it?.lifeArea == LifeArea.EPHEMERA){
                text = it.content
            }
        }
    }
}
<!-- etc. -->
```

So my question is: how do I handle this?
I'm thinking the only solution would be to 1) hold a Relation object with the EDITED attributes, updated whenever the user edits the editText, 2) store this in the database.

But I don't think this would be architecturally sound. Nor am I sure if it would work.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Yes. The ViewModel is basically designed to stay alive even if your activity gets destroyed and rebuilt (though beware: if you manually set your activity to null, or replace your fragment, the viewmodel is destroyed as well). So the solution is to have 2 versions of your object's data: 1 MediatorLiveData that holds the object as stored in the database, and 1 LiveData that's a copy of that object and which is data bounded to the layout. On saving, you just copy those values to the database-bound object and persist.

Comment: I'm not even sure if it's really necessary to hold a reference to the DB object, though, as you could just retrieve it using the id on saving.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you can try [Two Way Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way)

Comment: Don't just post a link tot a (possible) solution. Please give a brief  description how to solve the problem and an example if possible